# Prove $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+3\le 2\sqrt{a^3b+b^3c+c^3a-3abc+9}$ for $ab+bc+ca=3.$

Tags: inequality

While trying to solve a problem, I got the following inequality which appears correct, but I cannot prove so far.

> If $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3$ then prove that
> $$\color{black}{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+3\le 2\sqrt{a^3b+b^3c+c^3a-3abc+9}.}$$
> Equality holds at $(a,b,c)=\{(3,1,0);(1,1,1)\}.$

I've tried to use $SOS$ form as $$a^3b+b^3c+c^3a+27\ge 6(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a) \iff ab(a-3)^2+bc(b-3)^2+ca(c-3)^2\ge 0.$$Thus, we need to prove $$\color{black}{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+3\le 2\sqrt{6(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)-3abc-18}}$$which is not valid when $a=b=c=1.$

I also came up with the idea: Verifying $\sum_{cyc}a^3b\longrightarrow \sum_{cyc}a^2b$ as
$$a^3b=\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}a^2b-\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2-abc\sum_{cyc}a=p\sum_{cyc}a^2b-9+pr.$$Now, let $T=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a; a+b+c=p\ge 3; r=abc\ge 0$ the original inequality becomes$$T+3\le 2\sqrt{p(T+r)-3r}\iff T^2+6T+9\le 4Tp+4pr-12r.$$Or$$\color{black}{f(T)=T^2+T(6-4p)+r(12-4p)+9\le 0.}$$
Notice that $r(12-4p)=4r(3-p)\le 0,$ thus we just need to prove $$\color{black}{(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)^2+(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)(6-4a-4b-4c)+9\le 0. \tag{*}}$$
I got stuck here.

I was not sure that $(*)$ is correct or not. In case it is true, I hope you help me prove it.

Also, any ideas and comments is welcome. Thank you for your interest.

*Update.* My verified inequality is true $$\color{black}{(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)^2+(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)(6-4a-4b-4c)+9\le 0. \tag{*}}$$

Is there a nice proof for it or at least a proof can be verified by hand?

Comment: Indeed, you starting inequality it's true. BW kills it

Comment: Could you please tell more? Is is homogenous?

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that:
$$2\sqrt{\frac{ab+ac+bc}{2}\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^3b-abc\sqrt{\frac{ab+ac+bc}{3}}+(ab+ac+bc)^2\right)}\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}a^2b+3\sqrt{\left(\frac{ab+ac+bc}{3}\right)^3}$$ or $$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+3a^3b^3+4a^4bc+13a^3b^2c+3a^3c^2b+6a^2b^2c^2)\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^2+a^3bc+3a^2b^2c)$$ or
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+3a^3b^3+4a^4bc+13a^3b^2c+3a^3c^2b+6a^2b^2c^2)\right)^2\geq$$
$$\geq12(ab+ac+bc)^3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+2abc)^2,$$ which is obvious by BW:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x%5E4y%5E2%2By%5E4z%5E2%2Bz%5E4x%5E2%2B3%28x%5E3y%5E3%2Bx%5E3z%5E3%2By%5E3z%5E3%29%2B4xyz%28x%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E3%29%2B13xyz%28x%5E2y%2By%5E2z%2Bz%5E2x%29%2B3xyz%28x%5E2z%2By%5E2x%2Bz%5E2y%29%2B18x%5E2y%5E2z%5E2%29%5E2-12%28xy%2Bxz%2Byz%29%5E3%28x%5E2y%2By%5E2z%2Bz%5E2x%2B2xyz%29%5E2%2Cx%3Da%2Cy%3Da%2Bu%2Cz%3Da%2Bv

I think the last form of your inequality can get a nice solution, but I don't see it yet.

Comment: Does BW work for my last inequality?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, BW works. See my link